# Form input type equal to dynamic table result

Tags: php, forms, dynamic, html-table

How do I get the exact same "id" value, that goes in to my HTML table from the database, to also be entered into the form submit value?

**THIS IS WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR:**
I have generated two things that works fine:

1. a html table that generates the results from three columns from a database table
2. a "sell" submit button onto each row

[image: IMAGE OF THE TABLE]

As you can see in the code below. The value for "id" is fixed to the value of 3. So whenever I push the "Sell" button, 1 unit is added to the quantity column of product with id 3.

**PROBLEM:**
What I really want is for the value to be dynamic in accordance to the specific row.

If I push "sell" on the row for "ID 1", then I want "1" to be added dynamically as the value into the form. 

If I push "sell" on the row for "ID 2", then I want "2" to be added dynamically as the value into the form.. etc.

```
<html>
<body>

<form id="sellAndBuy" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="3">

<?php

echo "<table style='border: solid 2px black; text-align:left;'>";
echo "<tr><th>Product</th><th>Stock</th><th>ID</th></tr>";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "name";

echo "<td>";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT product_name, product_quantity, product_id FROM product ");
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    foreach ($result as $v) {
      echo "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>";
      echo "</td>";
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>' .$v->product_name. "</td>";
      echo '<td>' . $v->product_quantity. "</td>";
      echo '<td>' . $v->product_id.  "</td>";
      echo '<td> <button type="submit" onclick="askForSell()">  Sell  </button>  </td>
            <td> <button type="submit" onclick="askForBuy()">   Buy   </button> </td>';
     echo '</tr>';

     }
      echo "</td>";
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";

?>

<br>
<br>
<br>

</form>
<script>
form=document.getElementById("sellAndBuy");
function askForSell() {
    form.action="sellAndBuy.php";
    form.submit();
}
function askForBuy() {
    form.action="buyProducts.php";
    form.submit();
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass in the product id with the functions and then populate it into the input field like:

```
...

    echo '<td> <button type="submit" onclick="askForSell('.$v->product_id.')">  Sell  </button>  </td>
                <td> <button type="submit" onclick="askForBuy('.$v->product_id.')">   Buy   </button> </td>';

...

function askForSell(id) {
    form.action="sellAndBuy.php";
    form['id'].value = id;
    form.submit();
}
function askForBuy(id) {
    form.action="buyProducts.php";
    form['id'].value = id;
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested but the generated value is empty.

Comment: I got it working. Reason for the empty value before was that I missed "id" in askForSell(id). Big thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can submit variables depending on the button pressed without JS:

```
<button type="submit" name="id" value="1">Sell</button>
```

Also, buttons can contain the `formaction` attribute.